# Macro to open word through excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

```
Sub test()
    Set myWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=[B1])
    On Error Resume Next
    myWorkbook.Sheets(Cstr([D1])).Activate
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

How the above macro works :

- Mention excel path in cell B1
- Mention sheet name in cell D1

When macro is run it opens the specified Excel as well as the sheet.

Now looking for a macro that can open a Word document mentioned in cell B1.

Cell B1 will contain the path of the Word document.

Comment: Welcome to SU!  we're not a script-writing service.  I've issued a -1 since this information is very easy to find via a quick web search, and because you showed no attempts or research effort to actually get it working on your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Open_Word_Document()
    'Opens a Word Document from Excel

    ' Define Word object.
    Dim objWord As Object

    ' Create Word instance.
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    'Make Word visible.
    objWord.Visible = True

    'Load the file named in Cell B1.    
    objWord.Documents.Open Range("B1").Text

End Sub
```

Modified from the [source found here](http://www.teachexcel.com/free-excel-macros/m-42,open-word-doc-from-excel.html)